# C# parsing integer from text box correctly

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-express

I am learning C# (in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop) by converting a simple Windows Form application I previously wrote in Visual Basic.

The following code sends a text box entry and two integers to a method that returns a boolean, but throws an exception at runtime whenever the text box doesn't contain an integer (e.g 155 is OK, but 155.67 isn't).

```
if (!(rangeOK(int.Parse(cmTextBox.Text), 50, 250))) return false;
```

I've tried using TryParse to resolve this, but despite trying lots of online tips (and others' questions in here) I haven't been able to understand how I should do it.

If it helps the original VB code was:

```
If Not (rangeOK(Val(cmTextBox.Text), 50, 250)) Then Return False
```

Many thanks

Rob

Comment: Can you show your `rangeOK` method definition as well? It is not clear what you asking.

Comment: `155.67` is *not* an integer. You need to parse the data to `single`, `double` or `decimal`. Then you can try to cast the value to an integer.

Comment: My RangeOK method is
    private bool rangeOK(int userEntry, int minima, int maxima)
        {

            if ((userEntry >= minima & userEntry <= maxima))
                return true;
            else
                return false; 
        }

Comment: Thanks Bjorn-Roger, I understand that 155.67 is not an integer and will return false, which is what I want the code to do. Sorry for being unclear on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you use `TryParse`:

```
int result; // does not need to be initialized
if (int.TryParse(cmTextBox.Text, out result))
{
  if (!(rangeOK(result, 50, 250)))
    return false;
  // todo
} else
{
  // process error
}
```

More information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Good luck with it!

**UPDATE**

You can do the same with `double.TryParse` of coure, if you want to work with non integer numbers. More information here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Ah right, I see how that works now. Many thanks, Gabor.